# Accept ' (single quotation) or " (double quotation) from user in PHP

Tags: php, double-quotes, single-quotes

I created a input field in HTML, passed the value into PHP. When user provides a name with **' (single quotation)** in it my script is breaking. Upon debugging I found out PHP was issue. Can any one show me how to accept **' (single quotation)** and **" (double quotation)** 
Below is my code:

> HTML:

```
<label>Name: </label><input type="text" name="v1" id="text_input" size="30" required/><br><br>
```

> PHP:

```
$v1_name = $_POST["v1"];
```

FYI: Its not sql injection. I need to send that quote as string.

Comment: Database escaping. Prepared statements. etc.

Comment: [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60442#60442)

Comment: The question is not related to injection. How would I take the name. For example user name is  Todd O'Neil. I would like to take entire  name and convert into string.

Comment: If you're not inserting this into a database, just use http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: How does your script *break*? If you are indeed injection-protected, then quotes are characters like all others and shouldn't break anything. Double quotes are likely to break HTML feedback if used in input fields without escaping, though.